# Looping Formula In Excel From VB.net Speed

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel

**Whole Code Explained:**

I have this code that saves a txt file as a Microsoft Excel Comma Separated Values File (.csv) then opens a blank template excel file with a sheet named Graphs. It then copies the sheet with all the data from the csv file into the template excel file, renames it to "data" Then deletes the csv after close. The code then Inserts a chart in the "graph" sheet. Next it finds the total number of rows used and number of columns used for references for the ranges in the graphs and then for later formulas. This data is Acceleration from a accelerometer at a specific frequency. Therefor there is a lot of data, 8193 rows! The data lay out is top row labels (hz, Part1, 2...), Column A is frequencys, and all other cells from B2:whatever is accelerometer readings.

**The Problem** is it takes 83.22 seconds
to do the following loop, which inserts the average formula:

```
Do While i <= LastRow
        'Assign Range To Take Average
        CellLeft = wbtempXl.Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 2)
        CellRight = wbtempXl.Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, LastColumn)
        AvgRange = wbtempXl.Worksheets("Data").Range(CellLeft, CellRight)

        Average = appXL.WorksheetFunction.Average(AvgRange)
        wbtempXl.Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, LastColumn + 1).Value = Average
        i = i + 1
    Loop
```

After this Average formula I am adding peak finding logic to find the peaks and troughs in the data, but this step alone takes a minute and a half. Is there a fast, better way of doing this? Looping formulas that is.

Note: I can not just have the formulas in the template. The test could include 12 parts or 100 parts. Each part has its own column and the frequency is in the rows of column A. The rest of the Rows is acceleration readings per frequency. Would post picture but not allowed to yet.

Full Code:

```
Public Sub btn_Do_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_Do.Click
    Dim FileTXT As String = cbo_FileList.Text
    Dim folderpath As String = "C:\Users\aholiday\Desktop\Data Dump"
    Dim txtpath As String = folderpath & "\" & FileTXT & ".txt"
    Dim csvpath As String = "C:\Temp\" & FileTXT & ".csv"
    Dim FinalFile As String = "C:\Users\aholiday\Desktop\Test"
    Try
        File.Copy(txtpath, csvpath)
    Catch
        MsgBox("Please Choose File")
        Exit Sub
    End Try
    appXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    appXL.Visible = True
    wbcsvXl = appXL.Workbooks.Open(csvpath)
    wbtempXl = appXL.Workbooks.Open(FinalFile)
    wbcsvXl.Worksheets(FileTXT).Copy(After:=wbtempXl.Worksheets("Graphs"))
    wbtempXl.Worksheets(FileTXT).Name = ("Data")

    'Close Objects
    wbcsvXl.Close()
    File.Delete(csvpath)

    'Release Objects
    wbcsvXl = Nothing
    ' Declare Varables
    Dim Chart As Excel.Chart
    Dim ChartXL As Excel.ChartObjects
    Dim ThisChart As Excel.ChartObject
    Dim SerCol As Excel.SeriesCollection
    Dim Series As Excel.Series
    Dim xRange As Excel.Range
    Dim xCelltop As Excel.Range
    Dim xCellBottom As Excel.Range
    Dim yRange As Excel.Range
    Dim yCelltop As Excel.Range
    Dim yCellBottom As Excel.Range
    Dim CellRight As Excel.Range
    Dim CellLeft As Excel.Range
    Dim AvgRange As Excel.Range
    Dim Average As Double
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastColumn As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    ' Set i integer
    i = 2
    'Make Chart
    ChartXL = wbtempXl.Worksheets("Graphs").ChartObjects
    ThisChart = ChartXL.Add(0, 0, 800, 400)
    Chart = ThisChart.Chart
    Chart.ChartType = Excel.XlChartType.xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
    With ThisChart.Chart
        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = "RF Graph"
        ' X,Y title??????
    End With

    'Count Rows Used
    'Find last Row Used
    With wbtempXl.Worksheets("Data")
        LastRow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count
    End With
    'Count Columns Used
    'Find Last Column Used
    With wbtempXl.Worksheets("Data")
        LastColumn = .UsedRange.Columns.Count
    End With

    Do Until i > LastColumn
        'Excel Chart X Axis Values
        xCelltop = wbtempXl.Worksheets("Data").Cells(2, 1)
        xCellBottom = wbtempXl.Worksheets("Data").Cells(LastRow, 1)
        xRange = wbtempXl.Worksheets("Data").Range(xCelltop, xCellBottom)
        'Excel Chart Y Axis Values
        yCelltop = wbtempXl.Worksheets("Data").Cells(2, i)
        yCellBottom = wbtempXl.Worksheets("Data").Cells(LastRow, i)
        yRange = wbtempXl.Worksheets("Data").Range(yCelltop, yCellBottom)
        'Label Part in Data Sheet
        wbtempXl.Worksheets("Data").Cells(1, i).Value = ("Rotor " & i - 1)
        'Add New Series to Chart
        SerCol = Chart.SeriesCollection
        Series = SerCol.NewSeries
        'Rename and Assign Values
        With Series
            .Name = ("Rotor " & i - 1)
            Series.XValues = xRange
            Series.Values = yRange
        End With
        Chart.Refresh()
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    'Add Average Column Label
    wbtempXl.Worksheets("Data").Cells(1, LastColumn + 1).Value = "Average"
    'Rest i integer
    i = 2
    Do While i <= LastRow
        'Assign Range To Take Average
        CellLeft = wbtempXl.Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 2)
        CellRight = wbtempXl.Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, LastColumn)
        AvgRange = wbtempXl.Worksheets("Data").Range(CellLeft, CellRight)

        Average = appXL.WorksheetFunction.Average(AvgRange)
        wbtempXl.Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, LastColumn + 1).Value = Average
        i = i + 1
    Loop

    'Release Objects
    wbtempXl = Nothing
    appXL = Nothing
    GC.Collect()
    Me.Close()


End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you put formulas in the cells with code then convert to values if required:

```
    With wbtempXl.Worksheets("Data")
        formularange = .Range(.Cells(i, LastColumn + 1), .Cells(LastRow, LastColumn + 1))
    End With
    formularange.FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(RC2:RC[-1])"
    formularange.Value2 = formularange.Value2
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks, lightning fast haha. Can you explain the `R1C1`? what does it mean and how can I use this for a slope function instead of a looped ``SlopeValue = appXL.WorksheetFunction.Slope(XSlopeRange, YSlopeRange)``?

Comment: Excel can use 2 reference styles - A1 and R1C1. This code simply puts a formula in the cells using R1C1 notation - you could equally well use A1 notation here.

Comment: So could I use this with a Slope function?

Comment: You can use it with any function that you can put in a cell.

Comment: But I would have to use 2 ranges.. cause x1 x2 and y1 y2, I cant get it to work with slope. I need A2:A3 for x1 x2 then 2 averages for y1,y2. How can do split the range so it doesn't try to use the whole row? `"=Slope(RC:R[-1]C,RC[-1]:R[-1]C)"` something like this?

Comment: This is a completely separate question.